# Convert Date and Time to Current Millis (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, epoch

I'm using the Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker and Timepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), and I want to combine both of those values and get the current millis. I get the date in this format: "2015-05-19" [YYYY-MM-DD"] and the time as this: "10:57:19" [HH:MM:SS].

I saw that there is a Date.parse() method where you can get current millis but I couldn't find a way where you can include a time as well, and was wondering if there was a method for this?

Comment: Use the getTime method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp or so people don't freak out on me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a date and a time, you could use these to construct a date string:

```
var date = '1970-01-01';
var time = '00:00:00';
var dateString = date + 'T' + time;   // '1970-01-01T00:00:00'
var parsedDate = Date.parse(dateString);   // 0 Milliseconds
```

The 'T' is for handling timezones. Since I'm located in central Europe, my timezone offset is GMT+1 (Central European Time).

```
var newDate = new Date(parsedDate);   // Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the answer would be: `Date.parse('MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS');`

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

but you probably need to be wary of the time zone.